# Power inequalities

Tags: inequality

How would I show that:

if $ m^3 > n^2 $ then $ 3^{3k}m^3 > 5^{2k}n^2$

---

This is what I have done so far:

given $ m^3 > n^2 $; multiply both sides by $ 3^{3k}$, we get $ 3^{3k}m^3 > 3^{3k}n^2$

I am stuck here. Basically I need to prove that $ 3^{3k}$ > $ 5^{2k}$. Right? How would I do that? Perhaps solving with logarithm?

Comment: $3^{3k}=27^k, 5^{2k}=25^k$

Comment: since $27^k > 25^k$ and combine it with $m^3 > n^2$, can we say that $ 3^{3k}m^3 > 5^{2k}n^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.